# Scroll to the last element of a multi select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, scroll, multi-select

I have a function in jQuery that adds what's in a textfield in a selection box. The function is called when I click a button:

```
        addToList = function(textField, selectList)
    {
           var val = $('#'+textField).val();
           var select = $('#'+selectList);

           //If element does not exist already...
           if (select.find('option[value="' + val + '"]').length === 0 && val!="") 
           {
               //Add new element to the list
               $('<option>', {
                 value: val,
                 text: val
                 }).appendTo(select);

               //Clear text field
               $('#'+textField).val("");

               //Scroll down multi select and select automatically the added option
               //TODO: Scrolls only to selected element
                var lastOption = select.find("option[value="+val+"]");
                lastOption.attr("selected", true);             
           }
           else
           {
               if (val!="")
                {
                    alert("\""+val+"\" is already in the list.");
                }   
           }
    };
```

What I want, is that each time I add an element to the list, the list scrolls down to its bottom (which means that the last element of the list will be visible on its last line) and the added element will be selected automatically.

I found some code on SO to scroll down to a selected element, but I found no code to simply scroll to the end of the list, regardless of what's selected. I need this, because if I select the first element, this code just won't scroll!

Comment: have you looked at `scrollTop` function?

Comment: Yes. A lot! And it didn't help!

Comment: if by the term `list` you mean `select` tag, they are hard to work with which is why there are so many plugins available to replace them with more interactive html. In IE it is highly unlikely you will acheive what you want using `select`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var addToList = function(textField, selectList) {
    var $textField = $('#' + textField),
        $select = $('#' + selectList),
        val = $textField.val(),
        valueFilter = '[value="%s"]';
    if(val) {
        if($select.find('option').filter(valueFilter.replace('%s',val)).length === 0) {
            $('<option/>').appendTo($select).attr('value', val).text(val);
            $textField.val('');
            $select.val(val);//<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
        else {
            alert('"' + val + '" is already in the list.');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. Your code unselects what's already selected (I don't want this to happen) and does not scroll to the end of the list. :(

Comment: You will have to explain exactly what you mean by "unselect" and "scroll to". A demo would be good.